# Symfony - The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Symfony v 1.4

When the index action is called, the response code is 200;

```
homepage:
   url:   /
   param: { module: main, action: index}
```

When the show action is called, the response code is 500;

```
homepage:
   url:   /
   param: { module: main, action: show}
```

Module action:

```
class mainActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
  }
  public function executeShow(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
  }
}
```

I clear the cache using the php command symfony cc

Comment: You'll need to provide more info than that; make sure you're running in dev mode for whatever app you're running e.g `.../frontend_dev.php/...`

Comment: `<? php if (! in_array (@ $ _ SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'], array ('127.0.0.1', ':: 1'))) {die ('Вам не разрешен доступ к этому файлу.' .basename (__ FILE__ ). 'для получения дополнительной информации.'); } require_once (dirname (__ FILE __). '/ .. / config / ProjectConfiguration.class.php'); $ configuration = ProjectConfiguration :: getApplicationConfiguration ('applicationHelloWorld', 'dev', true); sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();`

Comment: That's the content of the file, read up on environments here: http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/05-Configuring-Symfony#chapter_05_environments

Comment: Obligatory hint, that Symfony 1.x isn't supported for a very long time now and you should definitely consider upgrading to at least 2.8 or even better 3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to identify your routes one by one with different names and urls:

```
homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: main, action: index }

show:
  url:   /show
  param: { module: main, action: show }
```

And you need to have templates for each one:

```
/apps/YOURAPP/modules/main/templates/indexSuccess.php
/apps/YOURAPP/modules/main/templates/showSuccess.php
```